# How to deal with different browsers (Safari, Chrome, Internet explorer and opera) in selenium webdriver. What kind of libraries needs to be installed?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, google-chrome, safari, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver. I have already created tests using Firefox driver but I am not able to work with the other browsers.

```
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        this.driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
        this.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

How to create the instance for other browseers. Resources I am using (.net, Nuget Package manager, c#, selenium webdriver)?

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Just like you're creating the Firefox driver you can create instances of SafariDriver, InternetExplorer, Opera, and ChromeDriver. See the selenium page if you need concrete initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the below Selenium WebDriver Documentation link.

[Selenium WebDriver Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)
Here you can find required details in a section called "Driver specific and Tradeoffs".